How to route Azure IoT Hub data to different Azure Data Explorer tables
I'm writing to seek assistance with a challenge I'm facing in loading IoT Hub Data into different Azure Data Explorer tables.
Context:
I have Python scripts simulating devices (energy meters) that successfully send data to IoT Hub. My goal is to load this data into three separate Data Explorer tables, each representing a specific type of energy: Gas, Water, and Electricity. (I would rather avoid using a type column.)
The crux of the matter is that most tutorials suggest creating routes in IoT Hub. However, none provide clear instructions on how to do this, and my searches haven't yielded satisfactory results. Additionally, I'd prefer not to use Event Hub, as it's supposedly possible to achieve this without it.
If anyone has insights or can guide me in the right direction, I would greatly appreciate it.
I managed to send IoT Hub data to one Azure Data Explorer table. However, I didn't manage to separate the data with routes.

please share the Python script /code that you have used to simulate devices (energy meters) that successfully send data to the IoT Hub in the above question. please read Please read  How to Ask, along with how to create a  minimal reproducible example.

To route Azure IoT Hub data to different Azure Data Explorer tables without using Event Hub, you can either route the data of the IoT Hub message to Azure storage and get the data from storage in Azure Data Explorer or use Azure Stream Analytics as an intermediary between IoT Hub and Azure Data Explorer.
Send a device telemetry to Azure IoT Hub using Python by following this document.

Route the data/messages of the IoT Hub message to Azure storage and get the data from storage in Azure Data Explorer:
. Follow this reference to route messages to a second endpoint, and this document to get data from Azure storage to Azure Data Explorer.





If have folder  path:

Using Azure Stream Analytics as an intermediary between IoT Hub and Azure Data Explorer:
Follow the steps below on how to achieve this:

Create an Azure Stream Analytics job in your Azure portal.

Create an Azure Data Explorer, database, and table.


Define Inputs: Configure your IoT Hub as the input source for the Azure Stream Analytics job.

Used this doc managed identities to access Azure Data Explorer from an Azure Stream Analytics job.

Define Outputs: Configure your Azure Data Explorer tables as the output sinks for the Azure Stream Analytics job. You'll need to provide the connection information for each table.


In the Stream Analytics job, write a query that filters the incoming data based on your criteria (e.g., energy type) and routes it to the appropriate output. You can use a CASE statement or WHERE clause to achieve this.

Once you've configured inputs, outputs, and the query, start the Azure Stream Analytics job.





